# Where can I get the iPhone 2.0 SDK?

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-sdk-2

I just set up a new macbook pro, installed xcode and the latest iphone SDK; However, I have an iPhone app that needs to target the 2.0 SDK.

I have 2.2.1, 3.0, and 3.1 available in xcode, but for the life of me cannot figure out where to get 2.0. I have scoured the iPhone Dev Center without any luck.

Answer (score 2):

The latest SDK allows you to target older versions.

You specify the SDK Xcode uses to build your application in your project’s Base SDK build setting, which you can set in:

> Project > Edit Project Settings > Base SDK for all Configurations

[alt text http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/art/project_info_general_base_sdk.jpg](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/art/project_info_general_base_sdk.jpg)

Read [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/120-Running_Applications/running_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH6-SW1) Apple page for more info.

Comment: Mine says iPhone Device 2.0 (missing), any way I can find it?!

Comment: That's strange... Try this older version of Xcode http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.0__final/iphone_sdk_3.0__leopard__9m2736__final.dmg

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes with the current X-Code but its only optional on installation. I could be wrong, I just installed X-Code last week and I think there were older SDKs available.